# Gridview -sorting event does not function

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Editable GridView that I'm attempting to add sorting functionalty to specified columns. Though I receive no errors, My sorting method does not work. Could I please get some help on what I'm missing here?

The Design:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLogNotice" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        ShowFooter="false"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="gvLogNotice_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowEditing="gvLogNotice_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating="gvLogNotice_RowUpdating"
        EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."
        DataKeyNames="LogNoticeID"
        AllowPaging="true"
        AllowSorting="true"
        OnSorting="gvLogNotice_sorting"
        Width="700px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Log No." Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("LogNoticeID")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogNoticeID" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text=' <%#Eval("LogNoticeID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Log Date" SortExpression="DateLogged">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("DateLogged")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateLogged" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("DateLogged") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Log Description" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" sortexpression="LogNoticeDescript">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("LogNoticeDescript")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogNoticeDescript" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("LogNoticeDescript") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Responsible Party" sortexpression="ResponsibleParty">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("ResponsibleParty")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtResponsibleParty" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("ResponsibleParty") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Planned Date" SortExpression="PlannedDate" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("PlannedDate")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlannedDate" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("PlannedDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
              </EditItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case Number" SortExpression="CaseNumber">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("CaseNumber")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaseNumber" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("CaseNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
              </EditItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Log Status" SortExpression="LogStatus">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("LogStatus")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogStatus" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("LogStatus") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/edit.png" Width="25"
                        Height="25" CommandName="Edit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <%-- <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/delete.png" CommandName="Delete"
                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete record?')" />--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

//Page Load Event:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "";
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            gvLogNotice.ShowFooter = false;
            //Load grid data using common method
            LoadGrid();


        }
    }
```

//bind data to GV and Load

```
void LoadGrid()
        {
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("selectActiveLogs", sqlcon);
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            try
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
                dt.Clear();
                da.Fill(dt);
                gvLogNotice.DataSource = dt;
                gvLogNotice.DataBind();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                sqlcon.Close();
            }
        }
```

//sorting event

```
  protected void gvLogNotice_sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.SortExpression)
        {
            case "DateLogged":
                if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                   LoadGrid();
                }
                else
                {
                    LoadGrid();
                }

                break;

           }

    }
```

Comment: Does your code on those lines literally start with `gvLogNotice.DataSource = //` or did you leave something out there? Because that is the key part.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx) page suggests that you need to set `dt.DefaultView.Sort` at some point to actually sort the grid, but I don't see it anywhere in your code...

Answer (score 2):

The `SortDirection` property on the GridView is changed only when the GridView is bound to a DataSource control using the `DataSourceID` property. Otherwise, sort direction needs to be managed manually.

In this case when we provide Data to gridView using its `DataSource` property , `e.SortDirection` will always return `Ascending`. **And therefore only your IF statement will always get executed.**

**Second Point::**  You need to optimize actually is just make sure you define a function to return the Data only. e.g say `LoadGrid()` only returns the DataTable. ***This way you don't need to define overloads of your LoadGrid() method***. Morover, with a proper way of implementation, overloading is really not needed at all.

**Third point::** is that you aren't applying sorting at all, but just loading the GridView.When you databind manually by setting the `DataSource` property and calling `DataBind()`, you need to handle the sort operation manually.

So, start by storing your sortDirection in ViewState. Simply define a public property to Get/Set the same. [ **NOTE** we need to store the sortDirection value according to point 1 above ]

```
public SortDirection SortDirection    
{ 
get { 
      if (ViewState["SortDirection"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["SortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["SortDirection"];
     }
set
    {
           ViewState["SortDirection"] = value;
    }
}
```

In your `OnSorting` event, Set the `sortDirection` as well as firstly sort the table and then load it into gridView.

```
 protected void SortRecords(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
     string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
     string direction = string.Empty;
        if (SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
             {
                  SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                  direction = " DESC";
             }
        else
            {
                 SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                 direction = " ASC";
            }
    DataTable table = this.LoadGrid(); // or this.GetDataTable(), to get only the DataTable
   // Now apply Sorting to your source of Data
    table.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression + direction;
   // Bind the GridView
    gvLogNotice.DataSource = table;
    gvLogNotice.DataBind();
}
```

And last, your LoadGrid is fine, only thing that just fill the table and return it

```
private DataTable LoadGrid()
{
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("selectActiveLogs", sqlcon);
      sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      try
       {
            sqlcon.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
       }
      catch (Exception ex)
       {}
}
```